# Getting slow response to node from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having 20 millions documents in my collection.I was coming across slow response issue.So I wrote a script to divide this collection into multiple collections.So now I am having one collection of 1.3 million documents.I took a random query to check response,so for a same query I am getting response time on bigger collection is around 19000ms & smaller collection is around 13000ms.I am using mongoose lib on node to connect with mongodb.
I am new to mongodb,so please tell me in which direction I should look to these issue.

Comment: Start by running your query in the Mongo shell [using `.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Comment: have you indexed the query fields?

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB cannot perform JOINS, so there is little gain from combining collections.But With MongoDB, and most other NoSQL databases, `Its easy to use separate databases in a single instance`. So if your data sets is large you can group them into different collections as per range keys,etc. Further breaking down those collections into different databases to gain performance. I'm little sceptical about the gain in performance but on theory it should.

for instance : Having two database to serve different data over entire million data sets in a single instance

```
db["collectionSet1"].AppCollection.find({application_status: {$in: ["pending", "approved", "rejected"]}}).sort({_id: -1})
db["collectionSet2"].OrigCollection.find({origination_status: {$in: ["originated", "approved", "rejected"]}}).sort({_id: -1})
```

Comment: I didn't get your point  "there is nothing connected with OP as there are not enough data"? Clearly he mention he is having 20M data. Also my suggestion is to try to break into collections and database sets. Now it may be case he will not have criteria for differentiating collections but he can always break them into different databases. Each db then can have different collections.